# Import a node with its path alias

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I'm using ne-impot and ne-export with drush for importing and exporting nodes. When exporting, as part of the uuid module, the URL alias is included with the export. However, when importing a node, the alias is not kept. I have tried using another custom module (https://github.com/kapasoft-config-scripts/designssquare_alias_path) that I found from this site: http://margotskapacs.com/2014/04/solving-menu-import-issue-when-featuring-sample-data-in-drupal, but that doesn't seem to be working either. Does anyone know of a way to import and export a URL alias along with the node from the command line? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to do this. I found it helpful for auto-aliasing URLs in bulk, and you can also customize it by using

```
function MyModule_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context) {

}
```

it works pretty well.